# I am not able to drop a FOREIGN KEY in MYSQL, problem with the syntax

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
emp_id SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(10),
last_name VARCHAR(10),
birthdate DATE,
sex VARCHAR(1),
salary SMALLINT,
super_id SMALLINT,
branch_id SMALLINT
);

ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY (super_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id);

ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id);

ALTER TABLE employee
DROP FOREIGN KEY (super_id);
```

I am not able to drop the foreign key after adding it. Trying to learn SQL, thank you for the answers.

ERROR - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(super_id)' at line 2

Comment: Note, it's 3 backticks `\`\`\`` for code, not 3 apostrophes `'''`

Comment: Why are you not able to drop the foreign key?  Do you get an error?  Always cut & paste the exact error message you get into your question.

Comment: I have updated the error shown in the body of the question. Please check.

Comment: Fk is dropped by its name (*fk_symbol* in MySQL terms), not by its expression. You must either specify FK name during its creation or look the name in SHOW CREATE TABLE before deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Give your constraint a name:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_employee_superid__employee_employeeid 
FOREIGN KEY (super_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id);
```

Drop it by name:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_employee_superid__employee_employeeid;
```

Comment: "fk_employee_superid__employee_employeeid" This is the name that we have given to the foreign key?

Comment: Not really sure what that means, tbh

Comment: @AyushSingh, The example shown above is not the name you have given to the foreign key. It's just an example of what it would look like if you had specified a name for the foreign key constraint. If you don't specify a name, MySQL generates a name. Run the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE employee\G` to see what the automatic name of the constraint is on your table.

Comment: So, the first part of my answer, when I said "give your constraint a name" and then added words of code `CONSTRAINT fk_employee_superid__employee_employeeid`  to the code you'd given.. That was me giving the constraint a name, that I then used to drop the constraint again later.